Zsh zinit load OhMyZsh plugin skipping aliases
I want to use these plugins using zinit to load git completions in zsh
zinit wait lucid for \
  OMZL::git.zsh \
  OMZP::git

But I don't care about the aliases, there are really too much aliases I already have my own.
How can I skip these alias definitions ?
I tried to disable alias command while plugin load but it doesn't work
zinit wait lucid for \
  atinit"alias alias=" \
  atload"unalias alias" \
  OMZL::git.zsh \
  OMZP::git

Any ideas ?

I found this solution that seems to work well
zinit wait lucid for \
  atinit'save_aliases=$(alias -L)' \
  atload'unalias -m "*"; eval ${save_aliases}; unset save_aliases' \
  OMZP::git

I also get rid of the library OMZL::git.zsh as I'm using powerlevel10k (it was redundant)
But after adding this trick to other plugins like kube or git plugins, there was a side effect as plugin loading system is done asynchronously.
I ended up with this that seems to work well so far,
I simply aliased alias command to nothing just before the plugin is loaded (make stage).
zinit ice as"completion"
zinit wait lucid depth=1 for \
  make'alias alias=' \
  OMZP::docker \
  make'alias alias=' \
  OMZP::docker-compose

Note: the alias command is restored at the end of the process so I guess that the commands added to make stage are scopped to zinit loading.
